# Why is summer EDT date modified +1 hr from media created time of video file?

Tags: windows, date, video, time

I have a question regarding DST. I live in Eastern USA/Canada with timezone UTC-5 (currently as of Oct 11, 2023).

We observe Daylight savings time UTC-5 from the first Sunday in November to second Sunday in March (winter timezone--autumn/winter seasons)=

We observe non-DST UTC-4 from Second Sunday in March to first Sunday in November (summer timezone--spring/summer seasons)

I have a video file that I imported to my PC using windows 10's explorer import pictures and videos and here are the stats:

filename: 20210905_164819.mp4
date modified: ‎September ‎5, ‎2021, ‏‎5:48:31 PM
media created: 2021-09-05 4:48 PM

Why is the date modified +1 hr from the media created ? How do I know when the video file was *actually* recorded ?

[image]

[image: This is DST and timezone settings]
[image: this is more information about the video file]